# MongoDB not starting in docker-compose but mongod.service does work

Tags: mongodb, docker-compose

I am developing some application with a MongoDB database, a Nestjs API and front-end in Angular.
Currently, we develop stuff locally then deploy it on a CentOS-based VM. To that end, we put everything inside a docker-compose.
However, although mongodb is in the "general" docker-compose, it has been running in a separate compose up to now.
My problem arose while trying to update the VM with our newest developments.
I used `docker-compose down` to turn down the mongod service, then wanted to run our other compose to upgrade the application.
However, mongodb failed and returned error code = 14. And now I can't launch it back from the dedicated docker-compose.
However, **I am still able to repair the mongodb.service** and access my database by using :

```
chown -R mongod:mongod /var/lib/mongo/
chown mongod:mongod /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
systemctl start mongod
```

What could be the problem here??
Here is the docker-compose file. From what I understand, it uses an image of MongoDB already built, so I do not have a Dockerfile.

```
version: '3.3'

services:
# API
  #nestjs:
    #container_name: nestjs_dev
    #image: nestjs-api:1.0.0
    #command: npm run start:prod
    # Default port
    #ports:
      #- 8080:8080
    #networks:
      #- nestjs-network 
    #depends_on:
      #- mongodb
    #restart: always
# Database
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: mongodb
    volumes:
      - /etc/mongod.conf:/etc/mongod.conf:z
      - /var/lib/mongo:/data/db:z
    # Default port
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    networks:
      - nestjs-network
    #restart: always
networks:
  nestjs-network:
```

Finally, I noticed that there is a 1-hour difference between "real" time, and the time in the log produced when trying to docker-compose up :
[Notice the 1-hour delta](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eb8Pw.png)

I was expecting the docker-compose to run mongod normally, as it always did.
Instead, mongod returned error code 14.

I tried the chown commands, changing the mongod.conf file, etc. Ultimately, I think it is an issue with my compose.

Edit : Here is the log from the docker-compose :

```
2023-02-19T17:42:05.031063000Z {"t":{"$date":"2023-02-19T17:42:05.029+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"-","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
2023-02-19T17:42:05.031365000Z {"t":{"$date":"2023-02-19T17:42:05.030+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915701, "ctx":"main","msg":"Initialized wire specification","attr":{"spec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":17},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":17},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":6,"maxWireVersion":17},"isInternalClient":true}}}
2023-02-19T17:42:05.031583000Z {"t":{"$date":"2023-02-19T17:42:05.031+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648601, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen unavailable. If TCP FastOpen is required, set tcpFastOpenServer, tcpFastOpenClient, and tcpFastOpenQueueSize."}
2023-02-19T17:42:05.033237000Z {"t":{"$date":"2023-02-19T17:42:05.032+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationDonorService","namespace":"config.tenantMigrationDonors"}}
2023-02-19T17:42:05.033460000Z {"t":{"$date":"2023-02-19T17:42:05.032+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationRecipientService","namespace":"config.tenantMigrationRecipients"}}
2023-02-19T17:42:05.033665000Z {"t":{"$date":"2023-02-19T17:42:05.032+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"ShardSplitDonorService","namespace":"config.tenantSplitDonors"}}
2023-02-19T17:42:05.033865000Z {"t":{"$date":"2023-02-19T17:42:05.032+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":5945603, "ctx":"main","msg":"Multi threading initialized"}
2023-02-19T17:42:05.034102000Z {"t":{"$date":"2023-02-19T17:42:05.033+00:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":6384300, "ctx":"main","msg":"Writing fatal message","attr":{"message":"terminate() called. An exception is active; attempting to gather more information\n"}}
2023-02-19T17:42:05.034424000Z {"t":{"$date":"2023-02-19T17:42:05.033+00:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":6384300, "ctx":"main","msg":"Writing fatal message","attr":{"message":"std::exception::what(): Operation not permitted\nActual exception type: std::system_error\n\n"}}
2023-02-19T17:42:05.168487000Z {"t":{"$date":"2023-02-19T17:42:05.167+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31380,   "ctx":"main","msg":"BACKTRACE","attr":{"bt":{"backtrace":[{"a":"555603E458D4","b":"5555FF067000","o":"4DDE8D4","s":"_ZN5mongo18stack_trace_detail12_GLOBAL__N_119printStackTraceImplERKNS1_7OptionsEPNS_14StackTraceSinkE.constprop.362","C":"mongo::stack_trace_detail::(anonymous namespace)::printStackTraceImpl(mongo::stack_trace_detail::(anonymous namespace)::Options const&, mongo::StackTraceSink*) [clone .constprop.362]","s+":"1F4"},{"a":"555603E47E19","b":"5555FF067000","o":"4DE0E19","s":"_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceEv","C":"mongo::printStackTrace()","s+":"29"},{"a":"555603E42167","b":"5555FF067000","o":"4DDB167","s":"_ZN5mongo12_GLOBAL__N_111myTerminateEv","C":"mongo::(anonymous namespace)::myTerminate()","s+":"D7"},{"a":"555603FCCBF6","b":"5555FF067000","o":"4F65BF6","s":"_ZN10__cxxabiv111__terminateEPFvvE","C":"__cxxabiv1::__terminate(void (*)())","s+":"6"},{"a":"555603FCCC31","b":"5555FF067000","o":"4F65C31","s":"_ZSt9terminatev","C":"std::terminate()","s+":"11"},{"a":"555603FCCD6B","b":"5555FF067000","o":"4F65D6B","s":"__cxa_throw","s+":"4B"},{"a":"555600F7647B","b":"5555FF067000","o":"1F0F47B","s":"_ZSt20__throw_system_errori.cold.24","C":"std::__throw_system_error(int) [clone .cold.24]","s+":"2F"},{"a":"555603FE8F69","b":"5555FF067000","o":"4F81F69","s":"_ZNSt6thread15_M_start_threadESt10unique_ptrINS_6_StateESt14default_deleteIS1_EEPFvvE","C":"std::thread::_M_start_thread(std::unique_ptr<std::thread::_State, std::default_delete<std::thread::_State> >, void (*)())","s+":"29"},{"a":"555601F1107A","b":"5555FF067000","o":"2EAA07A","s":"_ZN5mongo27startSignalProcessingThreadENS_13LogFileStatusE","C":"mongo::startSignalProcessingThread(mongo::LogFileStatus)","s+":"11A"},{"a":"5556011871EA","b":"5555FF067000","o":"21201EA","s":"_ZN5mongo11mongod_mainEiPPc","C":"mongo::mongod_main(int, char**)","s+":"B8A"},{"a":"555600F771BE","b":"5555FF067000","o":"1F101BE","s":"main","s+":"E"},{"a":"7F9113BC8D90","b":"7F9113B9F000","o":"29D90","s":"__libc_init_first","s+":"90"},{"a":"7F9113BC8E40","b":"7F9113B9F000","o":"29E40","s":"__libc_start_main","s+":"80"},{"a":"555601181A95","b":"5555FF067000","o":"211AA95","s":"_start","s+":"25"}],"processInfo":{"mongodbVersion":"6.0.4","gitVersion":"44ff59461c1353638a71e710f385a566bcd2f547","compiledModules":[],"uname":{"sysname":"Linux","release":"3.10.0-1160.83.1.el7.x86_64","version":"#1 SMP Wed Jan 25 16:41:43 UTC 2023","machine":"x86_64"},"somap":[{"b":"5555FF067000","elfType":3,"buildId":"BCB8F6C3AD4ABF41C81882BAE25C6885C6266CC4"},{"b":"7F9113B9F000","path":"/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6","elfType":3,"buildId":"69389D485A9793DBE873F0EA2C93E02EFAA9AA3D"}]}}},"tags":[]}
2023-02-19T17:42:05.171495000Z {"t":{"$date":"2023-02-19T17:42:05.167+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"555603E458D4","b":"5555FF067000","o":"4DDE8D4","s":"_ZN5mongo18stack_trace_detail12_GLOBAL__N_119printStackTraceImplERKNS1_7OptionsEPNS_14StackTraceSinkE.constprop.362","C":"mongo::stack_trace_detail::(anonymous namespace)::printStackTraceImpl(mongo::stack_trace_detail::(anonymous namespace)::Options const&, mongo::StackTraceSink*) [clone .constprop.362]","s+":"1F4"}}}
2023-02-19T17:42:05.172869000Z {"t":{"$date":"2023-02-19T17:42:05.167+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"555603E47E19","b":"5555FF067000","o":"4DE0E19","s":"_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceEv","C":"mongo::printStackTrace()","s+":"29"}}}
2023-02-19T17:42:05.173129000Z {"t":{"$date":"2023-02-19T17:42:05.167+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"555603E42167","b":"5555FF067000","o":"4DDB167","s":"_ZN5mongo12_GLOBAL__N_111myTerminateEv","C":"mongo::(anonymous namespace)::myTerminate()","s+":"D7"}}}
2023-02-19T17:42:05.173356000Z {"t":{"$date":"2023-02-19T17:42:05.167+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"555603FCCBF6","b":"5555FF067000","o":"4F65BF6","s":"_ZN10__cxxabiv111__terminateEPFvvE","C":"__cxxabiv1::__terminate(void (*)())","s+":"6"}}}
2023-02-19T17:42:05.173565000Z {"t":{"$date":"2023-02-19T17:42:05.167+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"555603FCCC31","b":"5555FF067000","o":"4F65C31","s":"_ZSt9terminatev","C":"std::terminate()","s+":"11"}}}
2023-02-19T17:42:05.173769000Z {"t":{"$date":"2023-02-19T17:42:05.167+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"555603FCCD6B","b":"5555FF067000","o":"4F65D6B","s":"__cxa_throw","s+":"4B"}}}
2023-02-19T17:42:05.173997000Z {"t":{"$date":"2023-02-19T17:42:05.167+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"555600F7647B","b":"5555FF067000","o":"1F0F47B","s":"_ZSt20__throw_system_errori.cold.24","C":"std::__throw_system_error(int) [clone .cold.24]","s+":"2F"}}}
2023-02-19T17:42:05.174219000Z {"t":{"$date":"2023-02-19T17:42:05.167+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"555603FE8F69","b":"5555FF067000","o":"4F81F69","s":"_ZNSt6thread15_M_start_threadESt10unique_ptrINS_6_StateESt14default_deleteIS1_EEPFvvE","C":"std::thread::_M_start_thread(std::unique_ptr<std::thread::_State, std::default_delete<std::thread::_State> >, void (*)())","s+":"29"}}}
2023-02-19T17:42:05.174451000Z {"t":{"$date":"2023-02-19T17:42:05.167+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"555601F1107A","b":"5555FF067000","o":"2EAA07A","s":"_ZN5mongo27startSignalProcessingThreadENS_13LogFileStatusE","C":"mongo::startSignalProcessingThread(mongo::LogFileStatus)","s+":"11A"}}}
2023-02-19T17:42:05.174675000Z {"t":{"$date":"2023-02-19T17:42:05.167+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"5556011871EA","b":"5555FF067000","o":"21201EA","s":"_ZN5mongo11mongod_mainEiPPc","C":"mongo::mongod_main(int, char**)","s+":"B8A"}}}
2023-02-19T17:42:05.174881000Z {"t":{"$date":"2023-02-19T17:42:05.167+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"555600F771BE","b":"5555FF067000","o":"1F101BE","s":"main","s+":"E"}}}
2023-02-19T17:42:05.175099000Z {"t":{"$date":"2023-02-19T17:42:05.167+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7F9113BC8D90","b":"7F9113B9F000","o":"29D90","s":"__libc_init_first","s+":"90"}}}
2023-02-19T17:42:05.175328000Z {"t":{"$date":"2023-02-19T17:42:05.167+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7F9113BC8E40","b":"7F9113B9F000","o":"29E40","s":"__libc_start_main","s+":"80"}}}
2023-02-19T17:42:05.175540000Z {"t":{"$date":"2023-02-19T17:42:05.167+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"555601181A95","b":"5555FF067000","o":"211AA95","s":"_start","s+":"25"}}}
```

Comment: I think the error code 14 indicates the incorrect clock settings and wrong file permissions on the server.

Comment: I saw that possibility, however mongod.service has no issue running, and I am able to access the database from my remote computer via Compass.
Therefore, if it is a clock issue, then it is a clock issue from inside the container. How may I solve that?

Comment: The docker-compose you are using is simply pulling the latest mongodb image from the Docker registry, mounting the volumes, specifying the port forwarding, along with the network. Did you try to run the docker-compose locally? I ran it, it works fine. Your mongodb will be running in a container.

You can also follow the container logs using: `docker logs -ft mongodb` and debug it. Can you do that and check whether it's working fine?

Comment: Can you confirm whether you still have any images. If you do, can you prune everything locally using: `docker system prune` and then re-run the containers to check whether the issue persists?

Comment: I edited my question to add the docker logs. I confirm that my other containers run without problem (well, they can't access the database because mongo fails with error14)

Comment: As I can see, I ran your docker-compose on my Ubuntu machine and it worked fine.



`2023-02-19T17:31:11.921100468Z {"t":{"$date":"2023-02-19T17:31:11.921+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23015,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Listening on","attr":{"address":"0.0.0.0"}}`

`2023-02-19T17:31:11.921138706Z {"t":{"$date":"2023-02-19T17:31:11.921+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23016,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Waiting for connections","attr":{"port":27017,"ssl":"off"}}`

Comment: Sorry for the lack of formatting of logs in the comments, however, after you've ran the container, can you check whether it's running or not?

Comment: You may check these logs in my edited question

Comment: Also, I insist : after trying to run the container, not only do I get code14, but now if I try to start mongod manually, I get an error (with `systemctl start mongod`). But I can "repair" it by doing :
`chown -R mongod:mongod /var/lib/mongo/
chown mongod:mongod /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
systemctl start mongod`